# SQLPLUS | OSERROR | O/S Message: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus

Sqlplus is throwing OSERRROR while running from Unix script .

O/S Message: Inappropriate ioctl for device

The Code was working and then suddenly without any change its giving OSERROR.

```
    sqlplus -s  $LOGON  > /dev/null    << EOF
    WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9;
    WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 9;
    set serveroutput off;
    set echo off;
    set termout off;
    set feedback off;
    set heading off;
    set linesize 10000;
    set numwidth 20;
    set colsep "|";
    set trims on;
    set trimspool on;
    set pagesize 0;
    spool Test.txt
    ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YY';
    Select * from Customer;
    spool off;
    EXIT;
    EOF
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that there hasn't been any change. Did you upgrade your OS? Do you run the command as the same user as before? Can you access /dev/null? Have you tried using `strace` to pinpoint the source of the problem?

Comment: No OS Upgrade And with the same user .  And I tried other queries those are working fine .

Comment: Which line causes the error? Could it be that the current directory is not writable?

Comment: Directory is having the same file which was created by other user and spool is trying to replace which caused the issue : Permission Denied . Resolved Now

Comment: That's a completely different error than you have in your question.

Comment: After Removing > /dev/null   , i can see permission error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directory is having the same file which was created by other user and spool is trying to replace which caused the issue : Permission Denied .

Resolution : Removed the old File which was generated by other User.